# Mac OSX & Xcode Image View

Tags: objective-c, macos

Thanks for reading!

Simple question I can't seem to find the answer to, what do you call this "splash screen" UI that appears when you press volume up, volume down, mute etc. on the Macbook Pro?

Also, could you link me to any documentation related to this type of UI in the Objective-C library? I plan to make it hold an image, darken the rest of the screen, and allow the user to control the position of this UI via coordinates send from iPhone. I could go more into detail but I don't want to overcomplicate this.

Example:

[image: UIImage]
<sub>(source: [edmunn.co.uk](http://www.edmunn.co.uk/i/highvolume.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is often called an Alert view or HUD (head-up-display).

You can find several implementations at github.

Like this one https://github.com/mobitar/MBAlertView

Comment: I think more common is HUD Overlay. No?

Comment: Ah fantastic sir, that's exactly what I'm after. I'll tick you once the timer on when I can accept an answer is up. Thanks for the speedy response!

Comment: @VladLazarenko depends I would say...so I mentioned "both".

Comment: epatel - I tried the github project above and it's all for iOS. I asked about OSX - can you provide any further information for OSX specifically?

Comment: Nope that one is also for iOS. It says it mimics the volume controls on iOS, but it's for use within iOS.